# Write bulk of data on USB port in Raspberry pi 3

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I want send data over raspberry pi3's USB port in byte format using python.This very new for me So I'm not able understand how can I do this.What packages needs to install and if any working sample code is their then anybody can share.How can I test this data is writing correctly on USB port or not.Please anybody can help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB does not support sending raw bytes. This is not a serial port.
You have to connect a device that declare itself as a Communication Device Class. The device and the host are going to wrap raw bytes in USB protocol.

Then you operating system will associate it to an endpoint.
Under Linux, the first device is associated to `/dev/ttyACM0`.
All you have to do the is to write to this endpoint.
Under bash: `echo some byte > /dev/ttyACM0`.

Here is an example. I have an arduino uno connected to my Linux Laptop.
Here is what the kernel says :

```
[37850.628522] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[37850.759206] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043
[37850.759215] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[37850.759221] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[37850.759224] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 12345678901234567890
[37850.759590] usb 3-2: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
[37850.833630] cdc_acm 3-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[37850.834040] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[37850.834044] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

The important part is : `ttyACM0`.

In python console, I can do :

```
with open("/dev/ttyACM0","w") as f:
    f.write("hello world")
```

The Arduino confirms it receives the bytes (RX LED blinks) and it acts according to its internal program.

Comment: Or they could act as a MSD host and send bytes inside a bulk write/SCSI packet to a mass storage device, or a device pretending to be one. But your answer is way easier. And saner.